# Flexible Hamburger menu, Transition not working with width and top simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a hamburger menu but I can't seem to make the `width` and `top` / `bottom` to work simultaneously 
here's my code:

```js
function disp_menu() {
  var lines = document.querySelectorAll("#hamburger span");
  if (lines[0].className == "") {
    lines[0].className = "topHamline";
    lines[3].className = "bottomHamline";

    lines[1].className = "midtopHamline";
    lines[2].className = "midbottomHamline";
  } else
    [].forEach.call(lines, function(l) {
      l.className = "";
    });
}
```

```css
:root {
  --hamline-height: 0.5rem;
  --ham-width: 4rem;
  --ham-gap: 2rem;
  --hamline-border: 1rem;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}

#hamburger {
  height: auto;
  width: var(--ham-width);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger span {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--hamline-height);
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: var(--ham-gap);
  border-radius: var(--hamline-border);
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
  transition: all 0.25s;
  position: absolute;
}

#hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
}

#hamburger span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 0;
}

.topHamline {
  top: 50% !important;
  width: 0 !important;
  transition: all 0.25s !important;
}

.bottomHamline {
  bottom: 50% !important;
  width: 0 !important;
  transition: all 0.25s !important;
}

.midtopHamline {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: all 0.25s !important;
}

.midbottomHamline {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 0.25s !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="hamburger" onclick="disp_menu()">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yq60rbh/14/)

what exactly am I missing here?

**EDIT**

I need the top line and the bottom line to transition to the middle while simultaneously reducing width

Comment: Plz, explain what you want it to look like... make it more clear!

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal my bad, I added what I need in the edit :)

Comment: I have added an answer, is that what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `translateY` the first and the third span `2rem` and `-2rem` respectively so they go to the center.

```
.topHamline {
    transform: translateY(var(--ham-gap));
    width: 0 !important;
    transition: all 0.25s !important;
}

.bottomHamline {
    transform: translateY(calc(var(--ham-gap) * -1));
    width: 0 !important;
    transition: all 0.25s !important;
}
```

**Check it in action below:**

```js
function show_menu() {
  var lines = document.querySelectorAll("#hamburger span");
  if (lines[0].className == "") {
    lines[0].className = "topHamline";
    lines[3].className = "bottomHamline";

    lines[1].className = "midtopHamline";
    lines[2].className = "midbottomHamline";
  } else
    [].forEach.call(lines, function(l) {
      l.className = "";
    });
}
```

```css
:root {
  --ham-width: 4rem;
  --ham-gap: 2rem;
  --ham-padding: 1rem;
  --hamline-height: 0.5rem;
  --hamline-border: 1rem;
}

body {
  background-color: #111;
}

#hamburger {
  height: auto;
  width: var(--ham-width);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: var(--ham-padding);
}

#hamburger span {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--hamline-height);
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: var(--ham-gap);
  border-radius: var(--hamline-border);
  transition: transform 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
  width: var(--ham-width);
  position: absolute;
}

#hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
}

#hamburger span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 0;
}

.topHamline {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--ham-gap) + var(--hamline-height)));
  width: 0 !important;
  transition: transform 0.25s, width 0.25s !important;
}

.bottomHamline {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--ham-gap) * -1 + var(--hamline-height) * -1));
  width: 0 !important;
  transition: transform 0.25s, width 0.25s !important;
}

.midtopHamline {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: transform 0.25s !important;
}

.midbottomHamline {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: transform 0.25s !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="hamburger" onclick="show_menu()">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

---

#### [Check it in action on Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/wvgWJEY)

Comment: The code seems to work in the given situation but can you add a variable solution?
like your solution doesn't work when I change the --ham-gap (https://jsfiddle.net/dx64vufL/1/)
like the hamburger menu I'm creating has variables so the menu can fit in any situation so I think you'll have to add calc() and var() to the `.topHamline` and `.bottomHamline`